# service console done loading trigger

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trigger, aura

I have an aura component in the service console. I would like to init the component only after the service console is fully loaded. is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What exactly are you attempting to do? Why do you need to wait?

Comment: @sfdcfox, my aura component (which gets case info via soql, sends it to a remote server, gets a response, and displays it) is slowing down the load of the case in the service console. users reporting that in some cases, some information will not load until my component completes its round-trip. I was sure that my init action is async, and It shouldn't stack other processes, but apparently I am wrong, and some kind of mutual exclusion is going on. I have no other leads, but to load the component after the parent page is loaded...

Comment: I also tried to find a lead to my core problem here: [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335537/service-console-waits-for-aura-component-to-finish-init-before-rendering-case), but all my efforts to even debug the problem were unsuccessful

Comment: What have you tried from my previous answer? Did you uncover any clues as to why this might be happening? A super-simple fix might be to wait calling the server for a fraction of a second (`setTimeout($A.getCallback(()=>{helper.fetchData(component);})),250);` This will let the component wait a little while before trying to contact the server, giving everything else a bit of time to load. Adjust 250 (this in 1/1000ths of a second) if it's not long enough.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I tried the obvious stuff like making sure the init function finishes immediately (leaving the request handling to promise), I tried to measure how much time it takes to fetch the data, but I couldn't find anything criminal there. the callout can take some time (5-6 secs, sometimes even more), but again, this happens in promise, after the init function has exited.